# scala types and inheritance misunderstanding

Tags: scala

could you explain me what is incorrect in this trivial example?

```
class C1 (val id: Int) 

abstract class C2 [T] {
    def m1 [T] 
}

class C3 [C1] extends C2
{
    override 
    def m1 (obj: C1) {
        println (obj.id)        
    }           
}
```

I have got: value id is not a member of type parameter C1
Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is several things at play in your example. Here is the example modified:

```
class C1 (val id: Int) 

abstract class C2 [T] {
  // don't repeat [T] and the method takes an arg
  // within C2, T refers to the type parameter
  def m1(t:T) 
}

class C3 extends C2[C1] {  // if in REPL put the brace on the same line
  // no override when implementing abstract 
  def m1(obj:C1) { println(obj.id) } 
}
```

This should compile (and run in the REPL).

Comment: Thank you.
This is exactly what I want :)

Answer (score 6):

By writing `class C3[C1]` you're saying that C3 takes a type parameter called `C1`. So inside the class definition of `C3` the classname `C1` refers to that typeparameter, not the class `C1`.

What you probably meant to write was `class C3 extends C2[C1]` (i.e. you're passing the class C1 as the type parameter for C2).

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion.
I rewrite C3 to

class C3 extends C2 [C1]
{
    override 
    def m1  [C1](obj: C1) {
    println (obj.id)
        
    }           
}

But I still have the same error.

Comment: @kolchanov That's because you did the same thing. If you write `def m1[C1]`, then you are saying `C1` is a type parameter -- some arbitrary type that will be provided at use-site -- which will _shadow_ the actual `C1` type.